# why does `awk` fail when I put it in a bash script

Tags: bash, awk

on the prompt:

```
ls | awk '{printf("%s\t\t%s\n", $9, $3);}'
```

succeeds in printing what it is supposed to be printing. If I put it in a file, I get four or five empty lines (about the number of lines in the output of `ls`):

```
$ cat awk-file-owner-simple 
#!/bin/bash
ls | awk '{printf("%s\t\t%s\n", $9, $3);}'
$ ./awk-file-owner-simple 
_
_
_
_
```

Where `_` stand for empty lines (that can't be displayed using the code formatter of stackexchange).

Comment: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)...

Comment: `ls` parsing is dead, long live `ls` parsing 8-)

Comment: @slm No matter your views on the subject, this instance of parsing `ls` is particularly brittle as it relies on words being in certain positions. File names with spaces in them would throw the whole thing off. The same with differing date formats depending on how long ago a file's timestamp was. Stop defending a practice that should be outlawed! :)

Comment: @JosephR. - that was a joke, I don't condone parsing `ls` either. It was meant more that we keep seeing these types of Q's come up even though it's been repeated over and over throughout the site to not do it.

Comment: GNU alternatives of showing file name and user name only: `find /path -maxdepth 1 -printf "%f\t%u\n"` OR `find /path -maxdepth 1 | xargs stat -c "%n %U"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `ls |` to `ls -l |`.

You have evidently aliased `ls` to `ls -l` in your shell (possibly a function and/or other options); use `type ls` to see what you're actually executing. Scripts don't get aliases, so it's just running the normal `ls`, with its single column of output.

Comment: Yes, I had: `alias ls='ls -la --color'`

Answer (score 0):

Or use stat(1) from coreutils package.

```
stat --printf="%-20n %U\n" *
```